# How can I make a text carousel for my site cross browser friendly by using javascript or html?

Tags: javascript, internet-explorer, firefox, browser, carousel

How can I make a text carousel for my site cross browser friendly by using Javascript or html? I have struggled with the code below because it will only work with Firefox but it fails on IE. Is there a way I can make it work on both?

```
<h4>Carousel-Text-Below </h4>

<html>
<head>
<script src='http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.6.2/jquery.min.js'    
type='text/javascript'></script>
<script type='text/javascript'>
$(document).ready(function(){
function setRandomWord(){
    var phrases =new Array("1-Blah Text","2-Blah Text","3-Blah Text");  
    $("#test").text(phrases[Math.floor(Math.random()*phrases.length)]);
}
setInterval(setRandomWord,3000);
});
</script>
</head>
<body> 
<p style="border:1px dashed gray; background-color:white; padding: 10px">
<span id='test'>Blah Text-Text-Text</p>
</span> Guaranteed Service or...Text---Text</strong></p> 
</body> 
</html>
```

Comment: So, what's the error in IE?

Answer (score 1):

I presume it is because you don't have a doctype set. Tried it here, and it works with `<!DOCTYPE html>` in front of the `<html>` tag.

Comment: You are right!!!But actually I have just discovered that the main problem is that I have not one but two carousels on the same page:one text and the other,image. They both function well together on the same page with Firefox ONLY but when on IE the text carousel fails because it takes an endless loop.

Answer (score 1):

Maybe IE is getting confused by your invalid HTML? Note that you're closing the `<p>` before closing the `<span>` inside it. Then you also have unmatched `</strong>` and `</p>` at the end. I believe you meant this:

```
<p style="border:1px dashed gray; background-color:white; padding: 10px">
    <span id='test'>Blah Text-Text-Text</span>
    <strong>Guaranteed Service or...Text---Text</strong>
</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/xrS3t/

Or maybe

```
<p style="border:1px dashed gray; background-color:white; padding: 10px">
    <span id='test'>Blah Text-Text-Text</span>
</p>
<p>
    <strong>Guaranteed Service or...Text---Text</strong>
</p>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/6nFVK/

I don't have IE to test right now, could you try the above jsfiddle links?

Comment: For me, in IE9 on Win7 both work, so perhaps it was indeed a markup problem, though weird that adding the `<!DOCTYPE html>` also fixed the problem.

Comment: Maybe the browser tries to fix broken HTML differently when in [quirks mode](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Quirks_mode).

Comment: Indeed. The script works but it turns out that it fails on IE (not on Firefox) if you use two carousels, one for text (like the above) and on for images. I do not know why. Thanks for your feedback.